# Pass list of fields to QuerySet.values( )

Tags: django, django-queryset

Is there a way I can pass a list of fields to be retrieved by the [QuerySet.values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values). I have a model and I want to retrieve different sets of fields from it on different occasions.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `*` operator to expand a list out into separate arguments when passed to a function, as described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the Python tutorial.

```
>>> qs = User.objects.all()
>>> values = ['first_name', 'email']
>>> qs.values(*values)
```

yields

```
[{'first_name': u'aaaa', 'email': u'a@b.com'}, 
 {'first_name': u'', 'email': u'abc@def.com'}, 
 {'first_name': u'', 'email': u'abcd@gmail.com'},
 '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
```

(I further truncated the output for brevity).

Comment: Brilliant! Could you please briefly explain why * works here?

Comment: @alexsalo That's a built-in python feature. I've added a link to the docs in my answer.